# Product Search Algorithm Best practice

Tags: c#, algorithm, backend

I concern about searching according to UI selection. For example i will search products with many parameters my code looking like that

```
if(param1 != null && param1 == 1 && param2 != null && param2 == 2 && param3 != null && paaram3 == 3)
{
}
else if(param1 != null && param1 == 1 && param2 != null && param2 == 2)
{
}
else if(param1 != null && param1 == 1)
```

There should be best way for this becouse there are very much possibilities like a polinom.

There should be a way predicate etc. for this. I dont want to write code like this

```
public ActionResult SearchProductVehicle(string CatagoryId, string MarkId, string ModelId, string HomeCat6,
    string productFuelType, string productCaseType, string productGearType, string fader1, string fader2, string fader3, string fader4, string startPrice, string endPrice,
string hdnInpSearch)
{
    if (CatagoryId == "-1")
    {
        List<Product> prdcs = Session["BeforeProducts"] as List<Product>;
        return View(new HomeViewModel
        {
            listpG = context.ProductGroups.ToList(),
            listCatG = context.Categories.ToList(),
            listMarks = context.Marks.ToList(),
            currencies = context.Currencies.ToList(),
            products = prdcs,
            cities = context.Cities.ToList(),
            listFuelTypes = context.FuelTypes.ToList(),
            listCaseTypes = context.CaseTypes.ToList(),
            listGearTypes = context.GearTypes.ToList()
        });
    }

    var products = new List<Product>();

    if (hdnInpSearch == null)
    {
        hdnInpSearch = string.Empty;
    }
    hdnInpSearch = hdnInpSearch.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
    if (hdnInpSearch == "Parça kodu, adı ya da açıklamasında" || hdnInpSearch == "İlan başlığı ya da açıklamasında" || hdnInpSearch == "Hizmet adı ya da açıklamasında")
    {
        hdnInpSearch = string.Empty;
    }

    var criteria = hdnInpSearch.Split(' ');

    var qry = string.Empty;

    // paged query should be ignore the other parameters
    if (Request.QueryString["page"] != null && Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["page"]) > 1)
    {
        CatagoryId = "";
        MarkId = "null";
        ModelId = "null";
        HomeCat6 = "null";
    }

    if (HomeCat6 == null)
    {
        qry = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?CatagoryId=" + CatagoryId + "&MarkId=" + MarkId + "&ModelId=" + ModelId + "&HomeCat6=" + HomeCat6 + "&hdnInpSearch=" + hdnInpSearch;
        Int32.TryParse(MarkId, out marId);
        //var marId = Convert.ToInt32(MarkId);
        var fChilds = context.Categories.Where(k => k.Id == marId).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();


        foreach (object obj in fChilds)
            types1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(obj));

        var sChilds = context.Categories.Where(k => types1.Contains(k.ParentId)).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();

        foreach (object obj in sChilds)
            types2.Add(Convert.ToInt32(obj));

        var tChilds = context.Categories.Where(k => types2.Contains(k.ParentId)).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();

        foreach (object obj in tChilds)
            types3.Add(Convert.ToInt32(obj));

        types3.Add(marId);
        crit = criteria[0].ToString();
        products = context.Products.Where(K => K.ProductType == 1 && K.IsActive == true && types3.Contains(K.CategoryId) && (K.Name.Contains(crit) || crit == string.Empty || crit == string.Empty)).Take(500).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        if (CatagoryId != "null" && MarkId != "null" && ModelId != "null" && HomeCat6 != "null")
        {
            Debug.Assert(HttpContext.Request.Url != null, "HttpContext.Request.Url != null");
            qry = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?CatagoryId=" + CatagoryId + "&MarkId=" + MarkId + "&ModelId=" + ModelId + "&HomeCat6=" + HomeCat6 + "&hdnInpSearch=" + hdnInpSearch;
            var subModId = Convert.ToInt32(HomeCat6);
            var fChilds = context.Categories.Where(k => k.Id == subModId).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
            var types1 = fChilds.Select(fc => (int?)fc).ToList();
            var crit = criteria[0].ToString();
            products = context.Products.Where(K => K.ProductType == 1 && K.IsActive == true && types1.Contains(K.CategoryId) && (K.Name.Contains(crit) || crit == string.Empty)).Take(500).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            if (CatagoryId != "null" && MarkId != "null" && ModelId != "null")
            {
                qry = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?CatagoryId=" + CatagoryId + "&MarkId=" + MarkId + "&ModelId=" + ModelId + "&HomeCat6=" + HomeCat6 + "&hdnInpSearch=" + hdnInpSearch;
                var modId = Convert.ToInt32(ModelId);
                var fChilds = context.Categories.Where(k => k.Id == modId).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
                var types1 = fChilds.Select(fc => (int?)fc).ToList();

                var sChilds = context.Categories.Where(k => types1.Contains(k.ParentId)).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
                var types2 = sChilds.Select(sc => (int?)sc).ToList();
                types2.Add(modId);
                var crit = criteria[0].ToString();
                products = context.Products.Where(K => K.ProductType == 1 && K.IsActive == true && types2.Contains(K.CategoryId) && (K.Name.Contains(crit) || crit == string.Empty)).Take(500).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                if (CatagoryId != "null" && MarkId != "null" && HomeCat6 == "null")
                {
                    qry = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?CatagoryId=" + CatagoryId + "&MarkId=" + MarkId + "&ModelId=" + ModelId + "&HomeCat6=" + HomeCat6 + "&hdnInpSearch=" + hdnInpSearch;
                    Int32.TryParse(MarkId, out marId);
                    //var marId = Convert.ToInt32(MarkId);
                    var fChilds = context.Categories.Where(k => k.Id == marId).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();


                    foreach (object obj in fChilds)
                        types1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(obj));

                    var sChilds = context.Categories.Where(k => types1.Contains(k.ParentId)).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();

                    foreach (object obj in sChilds)
                        types2.Add(Convert.ToInt32(obj));

                    var tChilds = context.Categories.Where(k => types2.Contains(k.ParentId)).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();

                    foreach (object obj in tChilds)
                        types3.Add(Convert.ToInt32(obj));

                    types3.Add(marId);
                    crit = criteria[0].ToString();
                    products = context.Products.Where(K => K.ProductType == 1 && K.IsActive == true && types3.Contains(K.CategoryId) && (K.Name.Contains(crit) || crit == string.Empty || crit == string.Empty)).Take(500).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CatagoryId != "null" && MarkId == "null" && ModelId == "null" && HomeCat6 == "null")
                    {
                        qry = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?CatagoryId=" + CatagoryId + "&MarkId=" + MarkId + "&ModelId=" + ModelId + "&HomeCat6=" + HomeCat6 + "&hdnInpSearch=" + hdnInpSearch;
                        var crit = criteria[0].ToString();
                        products = context.Products.Where(K => K.ProductType == 1 && K.IsActive == true && (K.Name.Contains(crit) || crit == string.Empty)).Take(500).ToList();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (CatagoryId == "null" && MarkId == "null" && ModelId == "null" && HomeCat6 == "null")
                        {
                            qry = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?CatagoryId=" + CatagoryId + "&hdnInpSearch=" + hdnInpSearch;

                            if (criteria[0] != string.Empty)
                            {
                                var tempPro1 = new List<Product>();

                                foreach (var sCriteria in criteria)
                                {
                                    var criteria1 = sCriteria;
                                    tempPro1.AddRange(context.Products.Where(k => k.ProductType == 1 && k.IsActive == true && k.Name.Contains(criteria1)).ToList());
                                    tempPro1.AddRange(context.Products.Where(k => k.ProductType == 1 && k.IsActive == true && k.Explanation.Contains(sCriteria)).ToList());
                                }
                                products = tempPro1.OrderByDescending(m => m.RecordDate).Take(500).ToList();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Contains("SearchProduct"))
    {
        HttpContext.Session["qry"] = qry;
    }
    if (HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Contains("GeneralSearch"))
    {
        HttpContext.Session["qry"] = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
    }
    else
    {
    }

    if (!products.Any() && CatagoryId == "null" && MarkId == "null" && ModelId == "null" && HomeCat6 == "null")
    {
        products = context.Products.Where(k => k.ProductType == 1 && k.IsActive == true).OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).Take(100).ToList();
    }

    if (productFuelType != null)
    {

        if (productFuelType.Trim() != "1")
        {
            var fuelType = Convert.ToInt32(productFuelType);
            products = products.Where(k => k.FuelType == fuelType).ToList();
        }
        if (productCaseType.Trim() != "1")
        {
            var caseType = Convert.ToInt32(productCaseType);
            products = products.Where(k => k.CaseType == caseType).ToList();
        }
        if (productGearType.Trim() != "1")
        {
            var gearType = Convert.ToInt32(productGearType);
            products = products.Where(k => k.GearType == gearType).ToList();
        }

        if (fader1.Trim() != "1960")
        {
            var modelYearStart = Convert.ToInt32(fader1);
            products = products.Where(k => Convert.ToInt32(k.ModelYear) >= modelYearStart).ToList();
        }
        if (fader2.Trim() != "2015")
        {
            var modelYearEnd = Convert.ToInt32(fader2);
            products = products.Where(k => Convert.ToInt32(k.ModelYear) <= modelYearEnd).ToList();
        }

        if (fader3.Trim() != "750")
        {
            var engineStart = Convert.ToInt32(fader3);
            products = products.Where(k => k.EngineCapacity >= engineStart).ToList();
        }
        if (fader4.Trim() != "10000")
        {
            var engineEnd = Convert.ToInt32(fader4);
            products = products.Where(k => k.EngineCapacity <= engineEnd).ToList();
        }

        if (startPrice.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
            var priceStart = Convert.ToInt32(startPrice);
            products = products.Where(k => k.CurrentPrice >= priceStart).ToList();
        }
        if (endPrice != null && endPrice.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
            var priceEnd = Convert.ToInt32(endPrice);
            products = products.Where(k => k.CurrentPrice <= priceEnd).ToList();
        }
    }

    List<Product> lpd2 = products.Take(3).ToList();
    string exp = "";
    foreach (Product p in lpd2)
        exp += p.Name + ", " + p.Code;

    if (products.Count > 0)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = exp;
        Category catt = null;
        string catname = "";
        if (products[0].CategoryId != null)
        {
            Int32 cidd = Convert.ToInt32(products[0].CategoryId);
            catt = context.Categories.Where(k => k.Id == cidd).FirstOrDefault();
            catname = catt.Name;
        }
        ViewBag.Description = catname + "/" + products[0].Name;
        City city = null;
        string cityName = "";
        if (products[0].City != null)
        {
            Int32 cityidd = Convert.ToInt32(products[0].City);
            city = context.Cities.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Id == cityidd);
            cityName = city.Name;
        }

        if (city != null)
            cityName = city.Name + ",";
        ViewBag.Keywords = cityName + catname + "," + exp;
    }

    Session["BeforeProducts"] = products;
    List<Product> prods = products.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).ToList();

    return View(new HomeViewModel
    {
        listpG = context.ProductGroups.ToList(),
        listCatG = context.Categories.ToList(),
        listMarks = context.Marks.ToList(),
        currencies = context.Currencies.ToList(),
        products = prods,
        cities = context.Cities.ToList(),
        listFuelTypes = context.FuelTypes.ToList(),
        listCaseTypes = context.CaseTypes.ToList(),
        listGearTypes = context.GearTypes.ToList(),
        ViewType = "VhicleProduct"
    });
}
```

please look that i hate this kind of code

Comment: Depends on what's inside those `{}`. With Linq you can dynamically compose queries.

Comment: @Henk please look my example

Comment: You are already using what I meant (with `products = products.Where(...)`). For the rest there now is way too much code here. Try to narrow it down to one compact example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to form complex queries.

like,

```
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

        if (param1 != null && param1 == 1 && param2 != null && param2 == 2 && param3 != null && paaram3 == 3)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.param1 == param1 && p.param2 == param1 = 2 && p.param3 == param3);
        }
        else if (param1 != null && param1 == 1 && param2 != null && param2 == 2)
        {
          ---------
        }
        else if (param1 != null && param1 == 1)
          ---------
```

and finally,

```
        dbContextContext.Products.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

There is an [Universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) also available, which doesn't require `LinqPad` and `AsExpandable()` extension.